# Specific $.ajax url relative paths work in FF & IE but not in Chrome

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is strange.  I have a jQuery $.ajax call below.  In Firefox it'll only work if I take out MyAppName.  In Chrome it will only work if I include MyAppName in the url.  Not sure why

I'm browsing to `http://localhost/MyAppName` when I test this.

**This works in FireFox and in IE 9**

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MyAppName/Search/Member/260491',
```

This does not work in FireFox or IE:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'Search/Member/260491',
```

**This works in Chrome**

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Search/Member/260491',
```

This does not work in Chrome:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: '/MyAppName/Search/Member/260491',
```

Comment: Both should work in all browsers. The issue resides somewhere else.

Comment: I was going to comment Ctrl+F5 when I first saw the question but apparently you already found out the caching issue, oh well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's $.browser() funciton in an if statement and correct the issue that way.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

> Example:

```
if ($.browser.chrome) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Search/Member/260491',
        ...
    })
}
else {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/MyAppName/Search/Member/260491',
        ...
    })
}
```

> Available Flags are:

- chrome
- webkit (as of jQuery 1.4)
- safari (deprecated)
- opera
- msie
- mozilla

Answer (score 0):

Might work in all browsers if you prefix it with "/", assuming it's a path from site root.

"/Search/Member/260491"

Comment: tried that, does not workin FF when I tried...when I do that I end up with http://localhost/Search/Member/260491 and it completely cuts out the MyAppName.

Comment: Are there any javascript exceptions in the console? Re last edit, are you able to change IIS settings, and set Site/App Root to "MyAppname/"?

Comment: nevermind I think it was a cache issue in the chrome browser or vice versa...it works fine.  This is a bad post.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict not really bad, can still show example of jQuery's if browser possabilities